# How to replace reference cell and have it affect the main cell if it referencing?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I asked a similar question on the Google Support Forum. I was wondering how I could reference a cell with any sort of value in it to another sheet (inside the same Google Sheets document) and then make it so I could edit the reference cell and have it edit the original cell as well.

You can already edit the original cell and see the updates on the reference cell. But how could I have it work the other way around? I am aware that I would need a script, so could anyone help with such a script?

Comment: Here you go:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tszarnBN_ISmsR7t5bv-t5iD_7tlaLZCgYlbWnTrAhs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the script would help, because this task is not doable in Google Sheets. Referencing referenced reference is a pure paradox and it's way beyond **circular dependency** which is able to be resolved up to some level.